# 2nd Order Differential equation with Unit Step and initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have some work but I can't get it to work quite yet, I need to solve this so I can plot it versus time.
The function is $90y''+30y'+1000(y-z(t))=0$,
$$z(t)= \begin{cases}0 & 0\leq t\leq5/9 \\ -\frac18 & 5/9<t\leq40/9\\0 & 40/9\leq t\leq 20/3\end{cases}$$
with $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$. I know $z(t)$ is a heaviside function but I am having difficulty moving forward. I've tried to simplify the main function to $90/1000y''+30/1000y'+y=z(t)$, and the heaviside notation I have is $z(t)=-\frac18u_{5/9}(t)$.
Help would be greatly appreciated. I apologize for the poor notation, I am new here and I do not know how to properly put in my functions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax formatting to mathematical expressions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to plot it, you can also get the values numerically

```
def z(t): return -1/8 if 5<9*t<=40 else 0

t = np.linspace(0,7,500)
y = odeint(lambda y,t: [ y[1], -(3*y[1]+100*(y[0]-z(t)))/9 ], [0,0], t)
plt.plot(t,y)
```

to get
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Do you know how I would convert this Python code to use in MATlab?

Comment: There is no ternary construct in matlab, so you would have to use `function v=z(t) v=0; if (5<9*t) and (9*t<40) v=-1/8; end`. Then you could also define the ODE function as an anonymous function. Or use a proper function, then you could also directly inline the computation of the `z` value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in an analytical solution . . .

Your ODE is
\begin{align}
\ddot{y}+\alpha \dot y+\beta y=\beta z,
\end{align}
where I've defined
\begin{align}
\alpha&=\frac{3}{9}\\
\beta&=\frac{100}{9}
\end{align}
for brevity.
Substituting
\begin{align}
x(t)=\gamma y+\dot y
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ satisfies
\begin{align}
\gamma^2-\alpha \gamma+\beta=0
\end{align}
reduces your ODE to
\begin{align}
\dot x+\frac{\beta}{\gamma}x=\beta z.
\end{align}
This has the solution
\begin{align}
x=e^{-\beta t/\gamma}\left(k_1+\int\beta e^{\beta t/\gamma}z\mathrm dt\right).
\end{align}
For the right integral
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{8}\int \beta e^{\beta t/\gamma}(\mathrm H_{5/9}-\mathrm H_{40/9})\mathrm dt,
\end{align}
using integrating by parts
\begin{align}
-\frac{\gamma}{8}\left((e^{\beta t/\gamma}-e^{5\beta/9\gamma})\mathrm H_{5/9}-(e^{\beta t/\gamma}-e^{40 \beta/9\gamma})\mathrm H_{40/9}\right).
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
\dot y+\gamma y=k_1e^{-\beta t/\gamma}+\frac{\gamma}{8}\left((\mathrm{exp}\left[\frac{\beta}{\gamma}\left(\frac{5}{9}-t\right)\right]-1)\mathrm H_{5/9}-(\mathrm{exp}\left[\frac{\beta}{\gamma}\left(\frac{40}{9}-t\right)\right]-1)\mathrm H_{40/9}\right)\equiv f(t)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
y=e^{-\gamma t}\left[k_2+\int e^{\gamma t}f(t)\mathrm dt\right],
\end{align}
where you could solve the right integral using integration by parts again.